# Show text by sliding up from the bottom of each line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm experimenting with jQuery, and came across a neat animation that I would like to recreate. 
In the website https://basicagency.com/, they show their text by sliding up from the bottom of each line of text, as to not move the element. The jQuery animation SlideDown shows text by taking the moving the whole block of text up and then down, which doesn't really create that effect. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Slide up animation in jQuery.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#text').slideDown();
});
```

```css
#container {

    position:relative;
    padding:40px;
}
#text {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#'>click me</a>
<div id='container'>
<p id="text">Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this website https://basicagency.com/ used css animate by:

**transform: translate3d**

, **transition**

for more details see : [CSS3 3D Transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp)